# android viewpager like image gallery

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

im trying to create an image gallery.

i have a `ViewPager` that each `Fragment` contains an image (swipable image gallery is what im trying to accomplish).
i also have a `GridView` that `onitemclick` triggers the `ViewPager` in the selected position showing the clicked image.
my problem is that one swipe to right and one swipe to left shows the same image as the clicked one.
ive tried setoffscreenpagelimit with no success.
this is my viewpager activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);
    helper = new WeddHelper(this,"wedd.db",null,1);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    Intent ing = getIntent();
    curr = ing.getIntExtra("curr", 0);
    byto = helper.getPhotos();
    count = byto.size();
    FragmentManager mg = getSupportFragmentManager();
   fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    for(int i = 0; i<count;i++){
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,GalleryFrag.class.getName()));            
    }
    mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments, this);
    pager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    pager.setCurrentItem(curr);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    mCurrentPosition = position;
    curr = position;
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}
public int getClicked(){
    return curr;
}
public byte[] getPhotoToBeDisplayed(){

    return byto.get(curr);
}
}
```

this is my custom adapter:

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private List<Fragment> fragments=null;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager=null;
private Context context;

public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager,List<Fragment> fragments, Context context) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    this.fragments=fragments;
    this.fragmentManager=fragmentManager;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();

}
@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
{
    super.setPrimaryItem(container,0,object);
}
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged()
{
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    fragmentManager.saveFragmentInstanceState(fragments.get(position));
}
public void replaceItem(int position,Fragment fragment)
{
    fragments.set(position, fragment);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

and this is the fragment:

```
public class GalleryFrag extends Fragment {
WeddHelper helper;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_fragment, container, false);
    ImageGallery myActivity = (ImageGallery) getActivity();
    int curr = myActivity.getClicked();
    byte[] photoToBeDisplayed = myActivity.getPhotoToBeDisplayed();
    helper = new WeddHelper(getActivity(),"wedd.db", null, 1);
    ArrayList<byte[]> imgs = helper.getPhotos();
    Bitmap br = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoToBeDisplayed,0,photoToBeDisplayed.length);
    Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgs.get(curr),0,imgs.get(curr).length);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), curr+"this is from frag", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragImage);
    iv.setImageBitmap(br);
    return v;
}
}
```